# Determine which action has been selected on Outlook Add-in icon click

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

I am implementing Action Commands on Outlook Add-in.
As you can see from the image below. my add-in gives you 3 options when you click on it and this choice will determine how the add-in will perform and what results you will get.

[image]

My problem is I am not sure how to pass the chosen tab value from manifest to my Add-in Application. I played with a bit and I think the value I need is under

> event.source.id

I open my add-in regardless of the choice so I am using but I need pass the selected value for the future use.

```
 <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">

     <SourceLocation resid="messageComposeTaskPaneUrl" />

 </Action>
```

Now question is how do I pass that ***id*** to the Add-in application.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a different Action node [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/action) for each of your Add-in Commands. Normally developers have a different URL for each TaskPane Add-in Command, or a different FunctionName for each UI-less Add-in Commands.) This is a better solution than trying to check the title.

If you still want to use the same URL for each of your Add-in commands, you could try embedding information as a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in your resid definition, e.g.

```
<Resources>
  <bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://yourpage.html?mode=Reply"/>
    ..
  </bt:Urls>
  ..
</Resources>
```

But it is recommended that you use unique URLs instead.